# Flex Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to use a button in my init() method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Test"
        creationComplete="init()">
```

Now when I try to do something with my button I get the error mentioned. I am assuming maybe it has not loaded yet?

```
function init():void{
     myButton.thisorthat == makes the error.
}
```

****EDIT*****
The button is created in MXML btw
Not that it matters, but this is for a flex mobile app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it *does* matter. One thing about NavigatorContent (assuming your children are a subset of one of these types of containers) to remember along with their halo counterparts is they all have a content creation policy set to deferred - meaning it creates the parent most layer of the view / viewstack, but not it's children until the user has actually navigated to that particular child. One *cheat* is to set the policy to 'ALL', but the better way is to actually listen for the **FlexEvent.CONTENT_CREATION_COMPLETE** instead (this is broadcast from the child of the navigation container).

Eg:

```
<halo:ViewStack id="setupStack" width="100%" height="100%">
    <api:FileSelector width="100%" height="100%" owner="{this}" 
                      enumerationMode="{FileSystemEnumerationMode.DIRECTORIES_ONLY}"
                      hint="{networkDbAccessHint}" />
    <!- this is valid, but not it's children until contentCreateComplete is fired -->
    <api:DataImport width="100%" height="100%" owner="{this}" />
</halo:ViewStack>
```

Both 'FileSelector' and 'DataImport' broadcast the event (extends s:NavigatorContent).