# How do I respond to a NavigatorContent being selected in a View Stack

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-spark

I have view stack in a app like so:

```
<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <views:LoginView top="0" bottom="0" right="0" left="0" id="loginView"/>
    <views:MainHomeView top="0" bottom="0" right="0" left="0" id="childSelectionView"/>
    <views:MainHomeView top="0" bottom="0" right="0" left="0" id="mainEvalView"/>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

When an event is fired, I call `viewStack.selectedChild = childSelectionView`

My question is how do I code a listener for the NavigatorConent being selected?

Here is what I try to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:NavigatorContent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:local="*" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    creationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        private function init():void
        {
            // Do something here
            advanceButton.visablitiy = false;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup>

    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button label="Advance" id="advanceButton" />
    </s:HGroup>
</s:VGroup>
```

I know that all the NavigatorConent's dispatch a creationComplete event on the application start, but their childrent aren't created yet. How did I respond to the on selectedChild change to self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it pays to poke around a bit, literally the question right before yours is exactly in the same problem domain. Use the FlexEvent.CONTENT_CREATION_COMPLETE event.

See [Flex Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098642/flex-error-1009-cannot-access-a-property-or-method-of-a-null-object-reference)

Answer (score 0):

```
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.events.IndexChangedEvent;

    protected function viewStack_childIndexChangeHandler(event:IndexChangedEvent):void {
        Alert.show('Selected Child: ' + viewStack.selectedChild.label);
    }

    ]]></fx:Script>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>

<s:ButtonBar dataProvider="{viewStack}"/>
<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack" change="viewStack_childIndexChangeHandler(event)">
    <s:NavigatorContent id="navigator1" label="Navigator 1">
        <s:Group>
            <s:Button label="N1"/>
        </s:Group>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent id="navigator2" label="Navigator 2">
        <s:Group>
            <s:Button label="N2"/>
        </s:Group>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. @mike.petty74 had the right answer.