# Adobe Flex : function called when item becomes visible?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder

I'm working in FlashBuilder 4.6 on a Flex app.  I want to know if there's a function that is called when a component (in my case a tab on a tabbed dialog mx:TabNavigator) becomes visible to the user?  I tried creationComplete and that is called for the 2nd and 3rd tabs in my dialog when the user clicks on them, but it's called for the first tab when the whole application opens, i.e. before the first tab is visible.

Thank you,
Fred

Answer (score 2):

InitializationComplete() is the function that is called when the children of a tab (Container) have been fully initialized.  I usually override this function in the Container that is a child of the ViewStack class/subclass in order to do set up on *first* show.  You can also listen for the show event to run code on subsequent shows. For some reason, the Flex team decided that the first time a component shows, it's not a show.

However, your problem is likely related to not fully utilizing the component life cycle. What's the full context?

Comment: I have a tabbed dialog that has 4 tabs.  3 of the tabs share common data (they all write to one config. file on the back end).  I'm trying to work out the best way to share the config. data between the tabs.  I have each of the tabs written as a separate mxml component.  My current approach is to have each of the tabs load the data in their creationComplete handler, but ideally I'd like to load the data for all 3 tabs when any of them are first viewed (i.e. lazy loading).

Comment: Ahh this makes more sense now, this is based on FlexEvent.CONTENT_CREATION_COMPLETE (children of NavigationContent have a content creation policy by default set to 'auto') Meaning the parent shell is created, but not it's children until actually navigated to by the user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098642/flex-error-1009-cannot-access-a-property-or-method-of-a-null-object-reference

Comment: Child views shouldn't be responsible for loading their own data. This should be supplied by the parent, so you could do something more like <yourNS:yourContainer sharedData={someData} /> and then your setter would have data that calls invalidateProperties, etc. Be aware that commitProperties() can happen before the children are created, so you need to invalidateProperties again in initializationComplete. http://www.developria.com/2009/11/handling-delayed-instantiation.html

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing which specific container you're using but all of them have some variant of the kind of event: **IndexChangedEvent.CHILD_INDEX_CHANGE**

This is triggered on a halo:Container which is the base for a TabNav, ViewStack, etc. The spark / air equivalents should have something similar.

Comment: Thanks Mike, my components are tabs in an mx:TabNavigator.  Also is there a general purpose callback called when a component becomes visible?

Answer (score 0):

Every UIComponent has Show Event, so you can listen for it in order to know when specific content in ViewStack becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an eventListener for its creationcomplete or click event along with its index and write specific actions to it. Code can be provided on request.